# Tooltip does not appear when applying <table> <td> overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

I have recently applied ***ellipsis*** on each `<table> <td>` and after that tooltip started giving me issues.

If you remove a class `.table` from `<table>` then you can hover on "Hover Me" link to see the tooltip which works fine. However, after adding a class I am getting issues with tooltip.

I need a solution in the below example. Please avoid giving me another solutions.

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
}

.table td, .table th{
    padding: .5rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.table td {
    max-width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.table td > div {      
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
    height: 1.5em;
}

.table td > div > p {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;   
}

.tooltip-stylish {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #666;
    text-align:left;
}

.tooltip-stylish h3 {margin:12px 0;}

.tooltip-stylish .top {
    min-width:400px;
    max-width:500px;
    top:-20px;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-30%,-100%);
    padding:10px 20px;
    color:#666666;
    background-color:#FFFFE0;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:14px;
    border-radius:8px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99999999;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    box-shadow:0 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display:none;
}

.tooltip-stylish:hover .top {
    display:block;
}

.tooltip-stylish .top i {
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:30%;
    margin-left:-15px;
    width:30px;
    height:15px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.tooltip-stylish .top i::after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(45deg);
    background-color:#FFFFE0;
    box-shadow:0 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
<tr>
  <th>
  Column with plain text
  </th>
  <th>
  Column with div
  </th>
  <th>
  Column with tooltip
  </th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="width: 30%;">
  This is plain text
  </td>
  <td style="width: 40%;">
  <div><p><strong style="color: rgb(77, 81, 86);">Hi, I was advised by a Patent Lawyer to publish a new concept (such as Anthropocene as an example) on Wikipedia. I developed this concept and I am in the process of registering the trademark and legal rights to it. During my research on Wikipedia I came across the following and would like to know how a new concept such as Anthropocene got onto Wikipedia, if the following is correctly understood by me.</strong></p></div>
  </td>
  <td style="width: 30%;">
  <div class="tooltip-stylish">
      <a>Hover me</a>
      <div class="top">
          <h4>Tooltip</h4>
          <ul>
              <li>
                  This is a tooltip
              </li>
          </ul>
          <i></i>
      </div>
  </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Where is the tooltip in action? I just see `hover` functionality here.

Comment: did you check the example? @Manjuboyz

Comment: I did, adding table class and removing it is showing same behavior, but I am not seeing a string `This is a tooltip` in the code you shared, am I missing anything here?

Comment: no, it works fine. remove <table class="table"> class from table in html code. It works fine after removing class from table.

Answer (score -2):

```css
.table td {
 max-width: 0;
 overflow: visible;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**You used table td `overflow: hidden` where your tooltip is actually overflowed. You can use `overflow: visible`** It'll show the tooltip.

Comment: after doing that change, text is overflowed on different td. It didn't work.

Comment: If you don't want your tooltip to overflowed on another td you can minimize your `.top` class width and add `left: 70%.`
it overflowed because `.top` class is `position:absolute` and It didn't had any parent relative classes